OrderBy custom field (Date) with multiple sections not working
I can't query and sort multiple sections in Craft 5:
using this code:
{% set entries = craft.entries()
 .section(['veranstaltungsgruppen', 'veranstaltungen'])
 .datum('< ' ~ heute )
 .orderBy('datum DESC')
 .limit(20)
%}

the order in the query is incorrect, first come all the 'veranstaltungsgruppen' entries, then all the 'veranstaltungen' entries.
Later on in the code I will paginate the results by
{% paginate entries as pageInfo, pageEntries %}

I am working on a live website with Craft 5.04 and MySQL 8.0.36 I tested this on a local site with  Craft Pro 4.5.9 and MySQL 8.0.33 and it is working there.
Edit:
ordeBy('title')

is working as expected

See here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/14821
